# Adding a second ec2 instance to target group causing "too many redirects" error (redirect loop)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm trying to set up Cloudfront->Application Elastic Load Balancer->Auto Scaling->EC2 AWS stack.

Everything works until it scales to more than 1 EC2 instance, which then causes a redirect loop with the error message "Too many redirects".

Here are the related settings:

1. I've enabled an ACM SSL certificate and attached it to the CloudFront distribution.
2. DNS pointed to CloudFront domain name.
3. Cloudfront 'Origin Protocol Policy' = HTTP Only
4. ELB Listener 1 = HTTP:80 redirects to HTTPS:443
   ELB Listener 2 = HTTPS:443 forwards to the target group of 2 EC2 instances
5. .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
```

Please help me solve this redirect loop and explain why the current settings are not working.

Any time you spend on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: @MarkB Each ec2 uses the same launch template. We don't create them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using both `mod_rewrite` and `RedirectMatch` to perform two different redirects:

This appears to redirect any request starting with `app.php` to the base website URL:

```
RewriteRule ^app\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This appears to be redirecting any request to `/` coming in to `/app.php/`:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
```

These rules seem to be in direct conflict with one another. If you try to request either the root website path `/`, or `/app.php` you are going to get into a redirect loop.

This condition tells Apache to track redirects internally in order to prevent a redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

However that only works as long as you have one server. When you have multiple load-balanced servers they can't track if a redirect has been issued by another server in the pool.

I suggest taking a look at these redirect rules and only using one of them depending on what your specific needs are.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'll look into this.

Comment: So you don't get a redirect loop until after you login? You didn't include any info about logging in and user sessions in your question. For the short term I would enable sticky sessions on the load balancer. Long term I would look into a distributed session store.

Comment: That did the trick for now. But like you said I need to find a solution now to save and distribute sessions evenly. Please update your answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this, temporarily, with Mark B's answer.

"You didn't include any info about logging in and user sessions in your question. For the short term, I would enable sticky sessions on the load balancer. Long term I would look into a distributed session store." – Mark B